# Tool to make a css-file match only a certain id

Tags: css

I need to include a css-file in my webpage, but the problem is that it should only match inside a certain div. Example:

Normal CSS-file:

```
#main td {
padding:20px;
}
```

Additional CSS-file:

```
.myclass td {
padding:0px;
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="main">
    <table><tr><td>TD with padding 20px</td></tr></table>
    <div id="inside" class="myclass">
         <table><tr><td>TD which should have with padding 0px, but get padding 20px; </td></tr></table>
</div>
```

This is only a simplified example - in the reality, the additional css-file is very long and complex (I need to include a tinymce, but the css-definitions here are only made by class and therefore overidden by the "normal" css-file).

My Q is: Is there a tool (perhaps in PHP?) which is able to change the additional css-file to work only on a special id? In the example, it should change all entries in the additional css-file to:

```
#inside .myclass td {
    padding:0px;
    }
```

and of course output a css-file with valid syntax.

Comment: Why can't you just modify the CSS file?

Comment: Probably he has a big css file :)

Comment: ;-) Yes, it's a big one and it's a 3rd-party one, so about to be updated/changed every few month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). It is written in ruby instead of php but it can easily do what you want using nested rules:

```css
#inside {
  .myclass td {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

Will compile to:

```css
#inside .myclass td {
  padding: 0;
}
```

To prefix every selector in a given file you can use a [nested import](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#nested-import) like in the following example:

```css
/* File vendor.scss */
.myclass td {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Your importing file:

```css
/* File main.scss */
#inside {
  @import "vendor";
}
```

This will give the same result as the example above.

Note that when using the nested import **your imported file has to be a `.scss` file**.

Comment: This sounds interessting. Could you give me a hint what to look for to "add" an id before all css-definitions in a file? The nested rules seem more to "compact" the css instead of limiting a css-file to a special scope.

Comment: @Werner: I've updated my answer with information on how to prefix every selector in a given file

Answer (score 0):

I like find and replace with regular expressions. Just replace:

```
^[^{]+
```

with:

```css
#inside $0
```

. It works on Notepad++, at the very least.

Comment: I am totally lost. Please explain!

Comment: @Jawad: This is find and replace. In your favorite text editor. It uses regular expressions. Google it.

Comment: On yes yes. LoL. And for a movement there I thought we have new combinators in CSS Selectors. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The RegExp works, bit not for css like:

     .myclass td, .myotherclass td {
     }

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, have you tried applying the class to the TD tag? Or, setting up the definition as .myclass TABLE TR TD?